# Objective-C: Can not instantiate method of another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am learning `iOS` and tried to create a utility class as following

**Common.h**

```
@interface Common
- (void) title: (NSString *) title withViewController: (UIViewController *) viewController;
@end
```

**Common.m**

```
#import "Common.h"
#import "PennyNavigationController.h"


    @implementation Common
    - (void)title:(NSString *)title withViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
        viewController.title = title;
        viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu"
                                                                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                                          target:(PennyNavigationController *) viewController.navigationController
                                                                                          action:@selector(showMenu)];

    }
    @end
```

and then I try to use in my `TableViewController` as

```
#import "Common.h"
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Common *common = [[Common alloc] init];
}
```

I get error on my IDE as

```
Cannot resolve method 'alloc' for interface 'Common'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized I was missing base class for the interface. The following works perfectly

```
@interface Common: NSObject
- (void) title: (NSString *) title withViewController: (UIViewController *) viewController;
@end
```